# What's the possible errors (or warnings) that a developer can face when deploys a smart contract into the Ethereum network?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

it's my first post here. I would like to ask, what's the possible errors that a developer can face while trying to deploying their smart contract into the Ethereum network.

For example, can it be "Out of gas"? and why does this happen? Could you please let me know or summarize any errors that will prevent them of properly deploying their contracts to the network?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For development purposes, you should definitely use testnet to avoid the gas related unease.